# Why does topological sorting of DAG have a time complexity of O(V+E) and not just O(V)?

Tags: graph

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Depth-first_search

The DFS solution to this problem has a O(V+E) time complexity. But why is not just O(V)? Yes we visit every vertex and every edge, but every edge just leads to another vertex, it's not an additional step. For example, if we have 2 vertex, with one edge between them, then we visit 2 vertex, period. We don't visit 3 things (2 vertex + edge). Give me an example of DAG where 'V+E' results in more visit than just 'V'

To strengthen my argument, the time complexity of a DFS on a binary tree is O(N), where N is number of nodes. No one says it's O(N+E).

Comment: In any tree, E = N - 1, so O(N+E) is the same as O(2N-1), which is just O(N).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a directed graph with *V* vertices, partitioned into two groups of size *V*/2, with an edge from each vertex in group #1 to each vertex in group #2. Then there are *V*<sup>2</sup>/4 edges, and you need to examine all of them.

Comment: good example. That convinces me that its O(V+E) for time complexity. What about space complexity? Is it fair to say that it's O(max number of edges in any given path in the graph) for the stack frame, and O(E) for heap space. ?

Comment: @user1008636 I think your assumption (O(max number of edges in any given path in the graph) for stack space and O(E) for heap space) is probably correct, assuming you are writing in C, C++, or another language that uses a runtime stack and that you implement the algorithm via recursion, and that you store your sorted results in a list on the heap.

Comment: It seems to me that (1) a tighter time complexity of this problem is O( num_disconnected_vertices + E) , in which a disconnected vertice is a vertice which has no edge connecting it to any other vertice, and (2) although O(V+E) is an upper (less tight) bound, it is always used instead of the tighter complexity in graph problems. Is that right?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: That's actually *not* a tighter bound; num_disconnected_vertices ≤ V ≤ num_disconnected_vertices + 2E, so O(num_disconnected_vertices + E) = O(V + E) — the two bounds are exactly equivalent, and neither is tighter than the other. (By the way, we say *vertex*, not \**vertice*, for a single vertex.)

Comment: @ruakh I don't understand your reasoning. AFAIK, if x and y are two upper bounds of an algorithm and x<=y, both O(x) and O(y) are complexities of the algorithm, but O(x) is a tighter bound than O(y).  If I understood your reasoning, if I follow it for polynomial complexities, given that n <= n^2 <= n^3 , O (n) = O(n^2) = O(n^3) , which is obviously wrong. Anyway, my point here is that the number of operations run for this algorithm is a function of num_disconnected_vertices+num_edges, not num_vertices+num_edges.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: I'm not sure exactly which part of my reasoning you didn't follow, but I'll try to walk you through it more carefully. To start with, though, I'm going to assume that you already understand that -- for example -- O(n) is *not* a tighter bound than O(2n), even though n ≤ 2n, because O(n) = O(2n). (If you *don't* already understand that, then please brush up on big-O notation.) So, here goes: as I wrote above, D ≤ V ≤ D + 2E. (Do you see why?) Therefore, D + E ≤ V + E ≤ D + 3E. Therefore, D + E ≤ V + E ≤ 3(D + E). Therefore, O(D + E) ⊆ O(V + E) ⊆ O(3(D + E)). *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* But O(3(D + E)) = O(D + E). Therefore, O(D + E) = O(V + E). Therefore, O(D + E) is not a tighter bound than O(V + E). (Does that all make sense?)